# pytesseract fail to recognise digits from binarized image

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am currently facing a problem with pytesseract where the software is unable to detect a number in this image:

[image]

For some reason, pytesseract doesn't want to recognise digits in this image. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import ImageEnhance, ImageFilter, Image

img = r'/content/inv_thresh.png'
​
str = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img), lang='eng', \
       config='--psm 8 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

It returns a string `COTO`

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you specify `--oem 3` (`Default, based on what is available.`)
2. Which model you use? Which tesseract version?
3. Tesseract expect clear image without artifacts to provide correct results => you will need better preprocess image.

I got following result with tessdata_best mode with recent tesseract (4.1/5.0alpha):

```
tesseract a9Uq4.png - --psm 8 --dpi 70
00308
```

Comment: Hi, I'm honestly not sure about what model I was using. I just simply `pip install pytesseract` then run the following command. I'm indeed got stuck with getting a clear image of digits. This should not be a difficult task, but it takes me a lot to get a correct digits from such images with just 5 digits

Comment: pytesseract does not install tesseract or tesseract model (pytesseract is just wrapper around tesseract). You did it. You should know/understand what you are doing otherwise you should be happy with random success.